# How to capture a specific line around a regex match in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell-3.0

So, here the example below.

```
Application Details for the XYZ application:
    =========================================================

    Application Name:       XYXZW1
    Application Id:         XYZ353WERX

Application Details for the XYZ application:
    =========================================================

    Application Name:       XYXZW2
    Application Id:         XYZ353WERX

Application Details for the XYZ application:
    =========================================================
 
    Application Name:       XYXZW3
    Application Id:         XYZ353WERX
    Secret Key:             XYZ86JBHHSD

Application Details for the XYZ application:
    =========================================================

    Application Name:       XYXZW4
    Application Id:         XYZ353WERX
    Secret Key:             XYZ86JBHHSD
```

Now I want regex to match only those "Application Name: value" which contain the "Secret Key: value" pair in windows powershell.
I am not sure this may be the regex reference and **it's not working on windows powerShell.**

```
$input_path = ‘C:\Users\Steve\Downloads\input.txt’
$regex = '\s*Application Name:\s*.*\r?\n\s*(?=Application Id \(ClientId\):\s*.*\r?\n\s*Secret Key:\s*.*)|\s*Secret Key:\s*.*'
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches |  Write-Output
```

All type of regexes work well on different platforms(tried few) but not on **Windows powerShell.**

The output should look like this:

```
   Application Name: XYXZW3 
   Secret Key: XYZ86JBHHSD 
   Application Name: XYXZW4 
   Secret Key: XYZ86JBHHSD
```

Comment: Try `(?m)\bApplication Name:\s*(.+)(?:(?!={3,}\r?$)[\w\W])*^\s*Secret Key:\s*(.+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/e2mB15/2, it will work if each section is split with 3 or more `=` signs. A variation of the same regex is `(?m)\bApplication Name:\s*(.+)(?:\n(?!\s*={3,}\r?$).*)*^\s*Secret Key:\s*(.+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it you need to use [look-arounds](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind).

`/(?<=Application Name:)[^\n]*(?=[^=]*(?=Secret Key))/g`

It captures everything between `Application Name:` and `\n` if after it `Secret Key` appears before `=` char.

It also captures all `space` chars as well. If you don't want it and you know exact number of spaces, then you can change it to

`/(?<=Application Name:\s{7})[^\n]*(?=[^=]*(?=Secret Key))/g`

`7` is the number of spaces to be skipped.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dXKmzA/1).

Update:

To also catch `Secret` value change to
`/(?<=Application Name:\s{7})[^\n]*(?=[^=]*(?=Secret Key))/g`

You need to handle two matches in a row as a pair of `Application Name` and `Secret Key`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RscDI9/1).

Comment: yeah, that's working but the output should look like this:

Application Name:       XYXZW3
Secret Key:             XYZ86JBHHSD
Application Name:       XYXZW4
Secret Key:             XYZ86JBHHSD

Comment: @Steve updated the answer according to the new description

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 capture groups if you want to get the value for Application name and Secret key

```
^[\p{Zs}\t]*Application Name:[\p{Zs}\t]*(.+)\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]*Application Id:.*\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]*Secret Key:[\p{Zs}\t]*(.+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[\p{Zs}\t]*` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `Application Name:[\p{Zs}\t]*` Match Application Name: and optional spaces
- `(.+)` Capture **group 1**, the value of for Application Name
- `\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]*` Match an newline and optional spaces
- `Application Id:.*\r?\n` Match Applicatino Id: and the rest of the line
- `[\p{Zs}\t]*Secret Key:[\p{Zs}\t]*` Match Secret Key: between optional spaces
- `(.+)` Capture **group 2**, the value for Secret Key

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WpailJ/1)

---

If you only want to match the value of the application name where there is a secret key present, you could also use lookarounds to assert the `Application Name:` to the left, and  `Secret Key:` to the right without crossing a line that starts with at least `==`

```
(?<=^\s*Application Name:\s*)\S.*(?=(?:\r?\n(?!\s*==).*)*\r?\n\s*Secret Key:)
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cs*Application+Name%3a%5cs*%29%5cS.*%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5cs*%3d%3d%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*Secret+Key%3a%29&i=Application+Details+for+the+XYZ+application%3a%0d%0a++++%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a%0d%0a++++Application+Name%3a+++++++XYXZW1%0d%0a++++Application+Id%3a+++++++++XYZ353WERX%0d%0a%0d%0aApplication+Details+for+the+XYZ+application%3a%0d%0a++++%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a%0d%0a++++Application+Name%3a+++++++XYXZW2%0d%0a++++Application+Id%3a+++++++++XYZ353WERX%0d%0a%0d%0aApplication+Details+for+the+XYZ+application%3a%0d%0a++++%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a+%0d%0a++++Application+Name%3a+++++++XYXZW3%0d%0a++++Application+Id%3a+++++++++XYZ353WERX%0d%0a++++Secret+Key%3a+++++++++++++XYZ86JBHHSD%0d%0a%0d%0aApplication+Details+for+the+XYZ+application%3a%0d%0a++++%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a%0d%0a++++Application+Name%3a+++++++XYXZW4%0d%0a++++Application+Id%3a+++++++++XYZ353WERX%0d%0a++++Secret+Key%3a+++++++++++++XYZ86JBHHSD&o=m)

Answer (score 1):

I would rely on capturing groups here:

```php
(?m)\bApplication Name:\s*(.+)(?:\n(?!\s*={3,}\r?$).*)*^\s*Secret Key:\s*(.+)
/\bApplication Name:\s*(.+)(?:\n(?!\s*={3,}\r?$).*)*^\s*Secret Key:\s*(.+)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2mB15/3/). *Details*:

- `\bApplication Name:` -  a whole word `Application`, space, `Name,` :`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:\n(?!\s*={3,}\r?$).*)*` - any amount of lines that do not start with zero or more whitespaces followed with three or more `=` chars up to the line end (`\r?` is added here only in case you will have to deal with regex where `$` with `/m` flag does not match before a CR char, as in .NET)
- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - one or more whitespaces
- `Secret Key:` - a `Secret Key:` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible